# R : Create a factor from two variables containing ranks and levels

Tags: r, dataframe, factors

Everything is in the title, I got from a database many columns, paired two-by-two containing codes and labels for some variables, I want an easy way to create half as many factors, with, for each factor levels/codes matching to the original two variables.

Here is an exemple of original data for two factors

```
|     customer_type    |  customer_type_name  |    customer_status   | customer_status_name |
|----------------------|----------------------|----------------------|----------------------|
|           1          |           A          |           2          |         Beta         |
|           2          |           B          |           2          |         Beta         |
|           3          |           C          |           1          |         Alpha        |
|           2          |           B          |           3          |         Gamma        |
|           1          |           A          |           4          |         Delta        |
|           3          |           C          |           2          |         Beta         |
```

i.e. a simpler way (simpler to call in a function for lots of variables) to do from dataframe "accounts"

```
a<-accounts[,c("customertypecode","customertypecodename")]
a<-a[!duplicated(a),]
a<-a[order(a$customertypecode),]
accounts$customertypecode<-factor(accounts$customertypecode,labels=a$customertypecodename[!is.na(a$customertypecodename)])
```

Comment: `interaction(var1, var2)`

Comment: But would definitely help if you explicitly showed your expected outcome for the example in your question.

Comment: No, no... interaction will take two factors, and create a third for every possible combination...

Well I don't know how I could "show" the output... the example given seems pretty clear, there are two variables customer_type and customer_status each one has two columns for matching codes and labels, it receives codes from one column (eg. customer_type) and labels from a second one (eg. customer_type_name).

the expected outcome would be for variable one 


    df$customer_type = c(1,2,3,2,1,3) and 
    levels(df$customer_type) = c(A,B,C)

Comment: I thought of something like this    
    

    x<-factor(df$customer_type) ;
    y<-factor(df$customer_type_name) ;
    x<-factor(x,levels=levels(x),labels=levels(y)) ;

but the order is incorrect